# Swift check if the class has encapsulate protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, encapsulation

how can I check if a class conform to encapsulate protocol?

Protocol:

```
@objc protocol Animation {
    func updateWithState (state: GKState)
}
```

Class:

```
class car : Entity, Animation {
}
```

Somewhere:

```
 if let myVC = entity as? Animation {
    myVC.updateWithState(nextState)
 }
```

works fine.

---

**While....**

Protocol:

```
@objc protocol Vehicle:  Animation {}
```

Class:

```
class car : Entity, Vehicle {
}
```

Somewhere:

```
 if let myVC = entity as? Animation {
    myVC.updateWithState(nextState)
 }
```

doesn't work, always False, never enter inside.

How can I check the protocol inside protocol?

Tanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Compiler error/warning runtime error? There is no reason why that should not work based on what you posted.

Comment: Mean is always False, I'll update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking through a playground it works without issue using pure Swift so if it is not working for you then maybe something to do with the @objc bridging see the image below for working playground.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I’ve  found my error, one protocol with @objc e the other without!